# Access docker compose containers from host NGINX via reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am facing this issues I am not able to solve by anything I´ve found on this site or anywhere else.

Lets assume I have a domain and Debian server with **NGINX** installed on it as main gateway for web server. On this domain (on root level) I have a traditional handling (like strippping www, redirecting everytime to https etc - basic stuff).

But now I´d like to have a set of services managed in `docker-compose` file that will be executed on docker start and these services will be **mapped as subdomains** to my main domain. Lets assume that domain has set up proper DNS records (these are not problem since I´ve been using subdomains for non docker services with no issues). For simplity take just one service- `pgAdmin4`- as example

Part of the NGINX configuration that solves this issue is pretty basic.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pg.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://pgadmin:81; 
    }
}
```

Docker compose is even more basic

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pw
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

When I try to `sudo nginx -t` to check the configuration, I am getting an error `host not found in upstream "pgadmin"`

When I try to replace name of container with `host.docker.internal` (with extra_hosts in compose set up like `"host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`) or when I try to use `127.0.0.1:81` or simply `localhost:81`, I am getting (after restarting NGINX) `502 Bad Gateway` whitelabel page error.

In logs I can see a lot of errors like

> *2 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 78.136.141.1, server: pg.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "pg.example.com"

```
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

Move nginx into Docker (and expose 80/443) using say this [container](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and then set env vars on the containers you want to expose that contain the hostname to map

e.g.

VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.example.com

There is even a [companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion) container that will handle setting up letsencrypt certs on the fly

Comment: Thanks for answer. Situation is way more complicated and I need to have some host nginx on top and contacting docker containers if needed. There is really no way how to achieve what I need? As I see it, the only problem is how to contact docker container from host

Comment: If you poke around that project it probably has all the parts you need, it will just be a bit of effort to get it to work, but you should still be able to host static stuff with the container